# XML data storage database? free and opensource

Tags: c#, xml

I need a way to store data inside xml files and write to differant parts of the file, as well as add elements and structure to the xml document.

I need full control over the file names and xml documents, and it would be much easier if I could use some kind of SQL layer to read and write from the xml.

Just due to project constraints I am tied into using XML, but if possible would like a trust and tested open source solution for this.

Or should I be using out of box .net functionality for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should be using out of box .net functionality.

the XML namespaces and Linq-to-XML will do this for you.

Comment: Also forgot to mention I am using .net v2 for this scenario.

Comment: .net 2 still has the XML Namespaces. It's just slightly harder without Linq-to-XML